# Maintaining current session across multiple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to migrate from [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), since request has been deprecated.

Suppose that the URL 'https://www.example.com' receives a post request with formdata that contains login information, and also suppose that I need to maintain the current session across multiple requests (for that I need a cookieJar).

Using axios I need cookieJar support from an external library therefore I use [axios-cookiejar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support). Also, to send formdata using axios I have to use the external library [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data), and I also have to set the headers manually since axios doesn't do that for me.

I have the following code, which uses axios that does just that:

```
axios = require('axios')
FormData = require('form-data')
axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default
tough = require('tough-cookie')
axiosCookieJarSupport(axios)
cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar()
form = new FormData()
form.append('email', 'example@gmail.com')
form.append('password', '1234')
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    data: form,
    headers: {'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}` },
    jar: cookieJar,
    withCredentials: true
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response['data'])
})
```

Using request this becomes much simpler:

```
request = require('request')
requestCookieJar = request.jar()
request.post({
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    method: 'POST',
    jar: requestCookieJar,
    formData: {
        'email': 'example@gmail.com',
        'password': '1234'
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
})
```

As you can see the request API is much more elegant. Is there a way to use axios more elegantly or is there a different elegant API, which isn't deprecated, that I could use to support my needs stated at the beginning of this question?

Comment: You should be wrapping the thing you use to make requests, so you can make any API you like. Incidentally had you wrapped request in the first place, your migration would be trivial.